# javafx Table view add datepicker

Tags: javafx

How can I add to the column of a javafx table view a datepicker for an inline edit?

```
<TableView fx:id="timelineTable" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
 <columns>
    <TableColumn fx:id="dateColumn" prefWidth="85.0" text="%timeline.date" />
 </columns>
</TableView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement your custom `TableCell` where you need to `@Override` the `updateItem` method. This method should set the graphic to be a `DatePicker`.
Alternatively, you will implement an editable `TableCell` where you only set the 
`DatePicker` as graphic when the cell is actually being edited.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code that might be helpful  to implement your idea:

Something more complete is [here](https://www.codeday.top/2017/10/08/48545.html).

```
Callback<TableColumn<String, String>, TableCell<String, String>> cellFactory = new Callback<TableColumn<String, String>, TableCell<String, String>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell call(final TableColumn<String, String> param) {

            final TableCell<String, String> cell = new TableCell<String, String>() {

                final DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();

                @Override
                public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                        setText(null);
                    } else {

                        setGraphic(datePicker);
                        setText(null);
                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        }
    };
```